# Vaadin: How to add 3 nested layouts

Tags: java, layout, nested, vaadin

I'm having issues with my UI in vaadin at the moment. I have my views connected with RouterLayout like this:

- -AppView (the main UI) | url: /
- --OperationsView (a nested layout inside a container in AppView) | url: /operations
- ---Operation1View (a nested layout inside a container in OperationsView) | url: /operation1 <-
  This isn't working

My declarations before any class are:

AppView declaration

```
@Route(value = AppView.ROUTE)
```

OperationsView declaration

```
@Route(value = OperationsView.ROUTE, layout = AppView.class)
```

Operation1View declaration

```
@Route(value = Operation1View.ROUTE, layout = OperationsView.class)
```

The problem is the third layout doesn't display correctly. It takes the whole page when accesed and mess up everything in the UI when going to another page. Shouldn't the url be: /operations/operation1 and not /operation1? However I can't get it to work correctly. Am I missing something? Or having 3 nested layouts is not possible with vaadin?

**A possible solution (?): Should I dismiss the third nested layout and add methods in the second layout to remove the contents in the container and display the items I want? I really don't care about url navigation in this one. This is the last thing I can come up with.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or having 3 nested layouts is not possible with vaadin?

It's possible. But are you implementing a `RouterLayout`in both  `OperationsView` and `AppView` classes?

Take a look into example here: [Multiple parent layouts with @ParentLayout](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/routing/tutorial-router-layout.html#multiple-parent-layouts-with-parentlayout). It has a set-up pretty close to yours.

```
public class MainLayout extends Div implements RouterLayout {
}

@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class)
public class MenuBar extends Div implements RouterLayout {
    public MenuBar() {
        addMenuElement(TutorialView.class, "Tutorial");
        addMenuElement(IconsView.class, "Icons");
    }
    private void addMenuElement(Class<? extends Component> navigationTarget,
            String name) {
        // implementation omitted
    }
}

@Route(value = "tutorial", layout = MenuBar.class)
public class TutorialView extends Div {
}

@Route(value="icons", layout = MenuBar.class)
public class IconsView extends Div {
}
```

> Shouldn't the url be: /operations/operation1 and not /operation1?

No, as in your `@Router` annotation you have specified that it's `operation1`. By specifying a `layout` you are defining the DOM structure, not the navigation route.From [docs](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/router/Route.html#layout--) :

> Sets the parent component for the route target component.When navigating between components that use the same layout, the same component instance is reused. Default layout target is the UI, but the layout should not be a custom UI as UI is a special class used to know where the route stack ends and no parent layouts should be involved.
>   All layout stacks will be appended to the UI as it represents the Body element.

**BUT** If you want it to be `operation\operation1`, you should use a `@RoutePrefix` instead [ParentLayout Route Control](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/routing/tutorial-router-layout.html#parentlayout-route-control)

> It takes the whole page when accesed and mess up everything in the UI when going to another page

Could you show a screenshot or add some details how it messes up?

Edit:

---

It's actually turned out to be harder to implement than I anticipated, but this seems to work:

`MainView.java`

```java
@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {
....
```

`OperationsView.java`

```java
//This is needed if you want "operations" to be accessible on its own
@Route(value = "operations",layout = MainView.class)
@ParentLayout(MainView.class)
public class OperationsView extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {

    Div content=new Div();
    public OperationsView(){
        System.out.println("operations view");
        add(new Label("operations view"));
        add(content);
    }
}
```

`Operation1View.java`

```
@Route(value="operation1",layout = OperationsView.class)
@RoutePrefix("operations")
public class Operation1View extends VerticalLayout {

    public Operation1View(){
        add(new Label("Operations view"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding @ParentLayout on the Operations Class did the trick, thanks man!